# How to verify if Windows Update location is properly configured from WSUS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, wsus

I was recently configuring a WSUS server. However I am not sure if I've set up correctly (WSUS isn't an everyday tool at the place where I work).

I've been wondering, Is there a command (or a tool) in Windows 7 that can be executed on a client machine and will verify the location from where the client is pulling the updates?

---

UPDATE:
It seems that the WSUS is working. The GPO is showing the clients as Kyle Brandt suggested.

However I just want to verify one more thing. Here's more info on the GPO i've created in order to distribute the updates.
[image]

Corect me if I'm wrong, I am not sure about `Target group name for this computer` option. Does it want as a value of the names of the **AD Groups** or the names of the **WSUS groups**? I wasn't sure so I include both of them - from the image you can see that I have put inside the relevant AD Groups and WSUS `Unssigned Computers` group

Comment: Target group comes from the definitions in WSUS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using Group Policy to configure your updates, you can query the registry for the Target Group and WSUS server values:

```
C:\> REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"
  WUServer    REG_SZ    http://fcsd-sccm
  WUStatusServer    REG_SZ    http://fcsd-sccm
  TargetGroupEnabled    REG_DWORD    0x1
  TargetGroup    REG_SZ    Servers
```

Or just get the `WUServer` value alone:

```
C:> REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate" /v "WUServer"
  WUServer    REG_SZ    http://fcsd-sccm
```

If the `WUServer` value is not present, you're connecting to Microsoft.

The Powershell equivalent:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate
```

Comment: Yup, that did it.. I guess I've set up the server correctly after all :)

Answer (score 3):

Look in the Windows Update control panel on the client machine. If you have WSUS configured properly, there will be a message that says something like "Updates are managed by your Systems Administrator".

Comment: In ours, although this may also be affected by policy, you end up with an option to check online for updates or check for system updates from the server managed by the administrator.

Comment: Yes, it is showing that message. :)

Answer (score 3):

Not a direct answer to your question, but....

I have always done this just by expanding "Computers::[OU]" in the Update Services screen in the WSUS server:

[image]

It shows the last report date for each computer in the OU. For this though, you will have to wait until the computer has checked for updates for the first time.

The `wuauclt` command might have an option to display the target update server, not positive though. It does allow you to force a check of updates with `wuauclt /detectnow` - when you kick that off though it sill takes a few minutes.

If you are telling each client what the update server is via GPO, you will also have to wait for the GPO to apply or use `gpupdate /force`

Comment: Oh, there is also a "Last Contact" Column you can enable there. Not sure of the specific difference on that...

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Kyle. It seems that the WSUS updates are working correctly. I've configured them via group policy. I will post an update to my question, I am interested in just one more thing.

Answer (score 2):

Run the gpresult tool on the client:

```
gpresult /h report.html
```

This will show you all GPO settings applied on clients.

Besides that, if you have access to a domain controller, can run the GPO Result Wizard, on `Group Policy Editor`

On the groups question, I think that you should group your machines by configuration, because you will want to approve updates based on machine configuration or windows version.

I personally, group machines by windows version.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the WindowsUpdate.log file.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902093